# bash - sanitize the script's parameters containing the '&' sign

Tags: linux, string, bash, parameter-passing, sanitization

I am writing a bash script and trying to do error handling and sanitizing the supplied parameters of the script. The supplied parameters have the form of key/value pairs and are separated by the '&' for the purpose of API compatibility:

```
cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2
```

In the simplest form, just to print out the supplied parameter, this script is just two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The supplied parameter"
echo "$1"
```

When calling the script with the parameters in single or double quotes, everything works as expected:

```
$./script.sh 'cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2'
The supplied parameters
cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2

$./script.sh "cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2"
The supplied parameters
cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2
```

However, if I don't single/double quote the string, it causes the script to hang:

```
$ ./script.sh cluster=xyz&tenant=abcd1234&key1=value1&key2=value2
[1] 1080
[2] 1081
[3] 1082
[2]   Done                    tenant=abcd1234
[3]+  Done                    key1=value1
$ The supplied parameters
cluster=xyz
```

And above stays until I press ctrl+c.

My question - how to properly sanitize the string when it is NOT enclosed in single/double quotes and prevent the above from occurring?

Bash version - `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do anything about it from inside your script - "damage" is already done before it is called. You need to make sure whatever is calling your script quotes appropriately

Comment: I know that bash is inherently dangerous...
So no other way except enclosing it to quotes or separating key/value pairs with spaces?

Comment: `&` is a special character for bash (and many other shells). It's interpreted when you enter the command, before your script starts running. Read `man bash`.

Comment: When `&` occurs as part of a shell command line outside of quotes and unescaped, it is a delimiter between commands (which makes the command before it run in the background). This is basic shell syntax, and you cannot make a command that does not conform to shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are only two ways to deal with the problem

**Option 1 - one parameter as a string, containing '&' signs**

One needs to ensure that the supplied parameters string is enclosed in single or double-quotes.

**Option 2 - get rid of '&' char entirely and interpret multiple supplied parameters**

The script should be called with multiple key/value parameters separated by space:

```
./script.sh cluster=xyz tenant=abcd1234 key1=value1 key2=value2
```